# Objectify - send autogenerated key into GWT client-side

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

How to reflect auto-generated key on server side into Entity in client side of GWT application?

Suppose I have new objectify entity with key field `@Id Long id;`

Before saving, value of id is null. After save key value was auto-generated and pojo was updated, but only on server side, not a client side. So when I push second time 'Save button' I get duplicate object in database, because new key value were generated.

How to deal with this?

Comment: This might help https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BasicOperations#Saving

Comment: There is nothing about how to update entity on client side, or I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the async interface, not calling now()?  Objectify does populate the autogenerated key into your POJO, but only when async Results are completed.

Comment: I was testing with now() and in fact it's update pojo but on server side only. And this is my problem.